# Flyout Opened and Closing event handlers not getting called

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

I have a Flyout template with attached closing and opened handlers but non of them are getting called

```
<Flyout x:Key="CameraFlyout" Placement="Right" Closed="CameraClosed" Opened="CameraOpened">
    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Enabled"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="400"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
        </Style>
    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
    <attachment:CameraCaptureControl x:Name="userControl" DataContext="{Binding}" />
</Flyout>
```

The flyout is attached to a button

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding CameraViewModel}" 
         BorderThickness="0"
         Background="Transparent"
         Flyout="{StaticResource CameraFlyout}"
         Content"Camera"/>
```

There should be something obvious that I'm missing here. The Flyout works I'm just not able to cleanup after it's getting dismissed, which sucks.

The handlers are defined in the code behind of the flyout template containing ResourceDictionary.

```
 public void CameraClosed(object sender, object o)
 {
     CameraCaptureControl.CleanupCaptureResources(sender);
 }

 public void CameraOpened(object sender, object e)
 {
     CameraCaptureControl.Initialize(sender);
 }
```

Comment: How are the `CameraClosed` and `CameraOpened` handlers defined?

Comment: Hmm your code looks fine to me. Where's your handlers n flyout style defined?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this post quickly Justin, I've added the Flyout templte definition. I'm guessing it might be a bug in Flyout class. handlers and flyout template are in a ResourceDictionary xaml and it's code behind. The button is in my UI.

Comment: Yeah you actually already included that bit of code. :) I was asking if you defined the style n the handlers all in one page's code behind?

Comment: I think the code placements are fine. I'll try skipping dictionary and putting the template inline, maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Not sure. But I tried your static resource way n it worked fine to me.

Comment: Did you do it on Windows 10 RTM?

Comment: Yes I did. Both handlers are called.

Comment: I am having the same symptoms with a timePickerFlyout.  Did you ever figure out why these events weren't firing?

Comment: The problem was with defining a static resource. Define them inline and all the methods get called.